# Pagination in a Wagtail project: Better way to separate pagination logic in model?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have here a snippet from a `HomePage` model in a Wagtail project that is acting as my blog index page. Since `get_context()` was getting a little lengthy while I was adding Django's pagination logic to it, I decided to try to put it in its own method and just have `get_context()` grab the paginated collection of `Page` objects from that. Here's how my code looked at first:

```
class HomePage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('description', classname='full')
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['posts'], context['page_range'] = self.pagination(self.get_posts())
        # End attempt
        context['home_page'] = self
        context['search_type'] = getattr(self, 'search_type', '')
        context['search_term'] = getattr(self, 'search_term', '')
        return context


    def get_posts(self):
        return BlogPage.objects.descendant_of(self).live().order_by('-date')


    def pagination(self, posts):
        paginator = Paginator(posts, 5)
        try:
            page = request.GET.get('page', '1')
        except:
            page = 1
        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        # Get a page_range
        index = posts.number - 1
        max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
        start_index = index - 5 if index >= 5 else 0
        end_index = index + 5 if index <= max_index - 5 else max_index
        page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]
        print('\n', posts, '\n')
        return posts, page_range
```

I didn't see the problem right away but of course noticed that no matter the `page` parameter in the URL, page 1 was being served. My quick and dirty solution was to just add `request` as an argument in `pagination()` and pass `request` to it up in `get_context()`. This solves the problem but I can't help but think there's a problem with this solution or that it's somehow not best practices. Can anyone tell me a better way to go about this and/or whether it's a bad idea to pass variables from function to function without being modified? Or is it actually fine?

Here's how my code looks now and things seem to be working alright:

```
class HomePage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('description', classname='full')
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['posts'], context['page_range'] = self.pagination(request, self.get_posts())
        # End attempt
        context['home_page'] = self
        context['search_type'] = getattr(self, 'search_type', '')
        context['search_term'] = getattr(self, 'search_term', '')
        return context


    def get_posts(self):
        return BlogPage.objects.descendant_of(self).live().order_by('-date')


    def pagination(self, request, posts):
        paginator = Paginator(posts, 5)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        index = posts.number - 1
        max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
        start_index = index - 5 if index >= 5 else 0
        end_index = index + 5 if index <= max_index - 5 else max_index
        page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]
        print('\n', posts, '\n')
        return posts, page_range
```

Many thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: I've been using El Pagination. It handles the logic through template tags, but makes it super simple to implement pagination on a website. https://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Seems reasonable enough to me. You're moving the pagination logic into its own method, and part of that logic involves retrieving the 'get' parameter from the current request, so it's expected that you'd need to pass in the request object in order for it to do its job.

Comment: @KalobTaulien El Pagination was my first choice but as somewhat of a newb I found the docs tough to work with. For example, it wasn't clear how to style the pagination in a template. I plan to revisit it a bit later when I feel more comfortable digging into source code.

Comment: @empathyattack yeah it was a bit tricky for me at first too. In your templates dir you add another dir called `el_pagination` and you can add `current_link.html`, `next_link.html`, `page_link.html`, `previous_link.html`, `show_more.html`, and `show_pages.html`. When you install the package you can view the templates it comes with, and you just override them with your own.